# How to make the entire background color of a div having different anchor elements clickable

Tags: css, html, clickable

I have an html where in one div is enclosing 2 anchor elements..
If I apply a style class to individual element with some background-color, the entire background is clickable.
If I apply a style class to the div, then both the anchor elements are displayed on the background, but the entire background is not clickable, only the individual anchor elements are clickable.

I dont want to use any JS or jQuery.

```
<div id="" class="AccordionTab" name="">
    <table id="Nickname_table" class="CommonTableClass" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="Nickname_tr">
                <td id="Nickname_td">
                    <a id="Nickname" href="#BalanceDisplay">It is my nick Names</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="AvailableTag_table" class="CommonTableClass" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="AvailableTag_tr">
                 <td id="AvailableTag_td">
                     <a id="AvailableTag" href="#BalanceDisplay" ">hi</a>
                 </td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Here AccordionTab is the style class having the back-ground color.

If I apply it `<a id="AvailableTag" class="AccordionTab"  href="#BalanceDisplay" ">hi</a>`

for a single anchor element, entire background will be clickable

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you want? If you set `a` background color, it affect all other element like `tr, td ,a`. right?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "clickable"?

I suspect that you're trying to program an accordion-style control with CSS alone.  However, generally speaking, CSS doesnt allow you to modify behavior.  That responsibility is left to the role of JavaScript.

In addition, CSS allows you to only target elements and their children, not their parents.  For example, you cannot select `Nickname_td` from the context of `Nickname`.  At least not in CSS3.  ([CSS4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) might provide this, but it's a long way off).

If you're looking to modify behavior based on the state of the document, I'm afraid you'll probably have to resort to some sort of JavaScript.